# select dynamically options in html select

Tags: jquery

I want to select options dynamically in a html select element by Jquery or JavaScript.
Is there any way for this.So, as soon as i select it , it will select as well as trigger the onchange event handler.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: <select><option value='1'>sun</option><option value='2'>moon</option><option value='3'>star</option></select>.Now i want to select the moon option in javascript or jquery dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value using [`.val("new value")`](http://api.jquery.com/val), and trigger the jQuery event handlers for the `change` event via [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change), e.g.:

```
$("selector for the select box").val("new value").change();
```

Comment: I am using  $('#yourselectID').val(value).trigger('onchange');                 It's working fine..Thanks.

Comment: @mns: That should be `.trigger('change')`, but yes, that's just the long-hand way of writing `.change()`.

Comment: .change() is just changing the value not triggering the event , if u have a working example can u pls share here the same